# Two-row notation and disjoint cycles

Tags: group-theory

$$\pi = (12)(13)(826)(58)$$
I am asked to express $\pi$  as a product of disjoint cycles.
I am given the answer $(513268)$, why is it not $(513)(268)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline x & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
\hline (58)x & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \color{blue}8 & 6 & 7 & \color{blue}5 \\
\hline (826)(58)x & 1 & \color{blue}6 & 3 & 4 & \color{blue}2 & \color{blue}8 & 7 & 5 \\
\hline (13)(826)(58)x & \color{blue}3 & 6 & \color{blue}1 & 4 & 2 & 8 & 7 & 5 \\
\hline (12)(13)(826)(58)x & 3 & 6 & \color{blue}2 & 4 & \color{blue}1 & 8 & 7 & 5 \\
\hline 
\end{array}$

Result : $1\to 3\to 2\to 6\to 8\to 5\to 1$ and $4$ and $7$ do not move.

$(12)(13)(826)(58)=(132685)$ which is the same as the stated $(513268)$.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to use this approach to future questions

Answer (score 2):

For the action of $\pi$ on $3$, we have 
\begin{align}
\pi(3)
&=[(12)(13)(826)(58)](3)\\
&=[(12)(13)(826)](3)\\
&=[(12)(13)](3)\\
&=[(12)](1)\\
&=2.\\
\end{align}
So $\pi$ maps $3$ to $2$.

Comment: Note: I have used the square bracket so as to distinguish the cycle notation (e.g. (23) as permutation sending 2 to 3) from the function notation ($\pi(3)$ as image of $3$ under $\pi$.)

Comment: I'm still not too sure how to interpret your answer, is there a different way to explain it?

Answer (score 1):

Because $3$ goes to $2$, not back to $5$.

Comment: Well that's implied, but why does $3$ go to $2$